# How to show the pager down the List on Yii with Bootstrap ClistView

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, frameworks

I want to show the pager down the list of index page...I am using bootstrap as themes in my application

here is my code

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
       'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,  
       'itemView'=>'_view',
       'template'=>'{items}',
```

)); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on your dataprovider setting

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('YourModelName', array(
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 5,
            ),
        ));
```

And add pager expression into template

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
       'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,  
       'itemView'=>'_view',
       'template'=>'{items}<br/>{pager}'
));
```

Updated:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'template'=>'<div class="bs-docs-example"><div id="yw121" class="grid-view"><table class="items table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">{items}</table></div></div><br/>{pager}'
));
```

[image]

Comment: it keeps going over the items...by default when you dont include the template section Yii put it down...but bootstrap view are forcing it to the top...

Comment: I guess you put the listview inside of table, the pager would generates a div make invalid format of table then the pager position goes to top. I've updated my answer, it was an idea how to separate your table structure with pager expression

Comment: Yes..i think that might be the cause...let me try your suggestion

Comment: thanks i just worked but i lost the column2 section...i dont see the operation section